# Api for moviereviews in python

Tags: api, movie

I need a free movie reviews api for python so I can create a simple program that tells the rating of a movie, also I need an api that doesn't require a key to use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [Simapi](https://moviesapi.com/), though it does not have access to ratings (those need an API key). It does offer some small amounts of movie metadata though. This is the only service that I know of that will allow you to access their data without an api key.

Running `https://moviesapi.com/m.php?t=avatar&y=&type=movie&r=json` returns:

```
[ { "id": "0499549", "title": "Avatar", "year": "2009", "poster": "N/A", "type": "movie" }, { "id": "0417299", "title": "Avatar: The Last Airbender", "year": "2005", "poster": "N/A", "type": "movie" }, { "id": "0120347", "title": "Tomorrow Never Dies", "year": "1997", "poster": "N/A", "type": "movie" }, { "id": "1133985", "title": "Green Lantern", "year": "2011", "poster": "N/A", "type": "movie" }, { "id": "1630029", "title": "Avatar 2", "year": "2020", "poster": "N/A", "type": "movie" } ]
```

Is there a particular reason for your aversion to API keys? Many API services allow you to use your data without even registering a credit card, and it can be as simple as adding `?apikey={{YOURAPIKEY}}` to a request.

I've used `http://www.omdbapi.com/` ([omDB](http://www.omdbapi.com/)) before in school and personal projects, and they are very helpful!

Hope it helps.

**EDIT**

omDB does charge now, but it's only 1$ a month. I would highly recommend it!

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks